# sqlite3 fts4 "error database table is locked"

Tags: sqlite, virtual, lazarus

Ubuntu 16.04, Lazarus 1.8.2, SQLite 3.11 (everything up to date)

This used to work just fine until about a month back and only now do I have some spare time to figure it out.

I mostly get "error database table is locked" and have checked the SQLite pages and the two reasons they give for this crash do not apply.

I sometimes get an error "vtable constructor failed: tFind" which I think is the real underlying issue as when stepping through, it crashes at the ExecSQL line.

Any thoughts? I am using the following code

```
const fldsEmails = ' fldActive, fldFrom, fldTo ';

sqlStr:='CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tFind USING FTS4('+fldsEmails+');';
dm.sqlFind.SQL.Text:=sqlStr;
dm.sqlFind.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: Do you have the DB open at design-time in the IDE?  If so that could be the source of the problem, in that what you are trying to do at run-time may require Sqlite to obtain an exclusive lock on the DB.  Perhaps it cannot do that if the DB open in the IDE.

Comment: @MartynA : Thanks for the comment, but no. I had tried closing before the "create" call. Plus his is happening when running as a stand-alone program outside of the IDE.

Comment: I definitely ran into this problem a few months ago when I was trying out Ubuntu. and something I googled (I think from the fpc wibsite) provided a simple fix.  I'll see if I can retrace my steps.

Comment: @MartynA : Thanks, I will also keep searching too, I appreciate your help though.